# Links need to be clicked twice after scrolling on mobile (with back to top button and scroll event)

Tags: javascript, css, ios, google-chrome, safari

So I have a website with a sticky menu and a back to top button that only show when scrolling down a few pixels. I have a scroll event listener for that:

```
        document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
            document.getElementById('return-to-top').style.display = 'block';
        });
```

The button is actually an anchor with the following CSS:

```
#return-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 60px;
    right: 15px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
    -moz-border-radius: 35px;
    border-radius: 35px;
}
```

On mobile Safari and Chrome for iOS, after I scroll the page down and the button shows up, some links on the page have to be clicked twice or else they don't work. In Safari some are working and some are not the first click, but in Chrome none of them on the first click.

Some recent info on the internet says there is a bug in iOS (from december last year).

Anyone have any ideas?